# Css drop down navbar causing below contents to move

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

The css hover drop down worked perfectly on fresh page, but it is not working when pasted on html page which is linked with bootstrap (I hided other css pages so I found bootstrap causing  the problem!)

So using devtool I hided 'position:absolute' from 'dropdown-contents' which is working but the below container jumping downward:http://prntscr.com/lu7frm

Here is the code:

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
/*  background-color: #333;*/
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #060606;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #060606;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
color:#4389dc;
transition:.3s ease-out;
}

.dropdown-contents {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contents a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-contents a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-contents {
  display: block;
}
/*navbar*/
#slapper {
    min-height: 2%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" style="padding:0px;">
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#home">For Professionals</a>
<a href="#home">Tax News</a>
  <a href="#home">Ask a Question</a>
  <a href="#news">Find an Accountant </a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Learn About Taxes 
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-contents">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `overflow:hidden` from you code (`.navbar` and `.dropdown`) to be able to see the dropdown. You no more need them to clear the float as bootstrap is already doing this.

```css
.navbar {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-color:#000!important; /*to show that the height is good*/
}

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #060606;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #060606;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
color:#4389dc;
transition:.3s ease-out;
}

.dropdown-contents {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-contents a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-contents a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-contents {
  display: block;
}
/*navbar*/
#slapper {
    min-height: 2%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container" style="padding:0px;">
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#home">For Professionals</a>
<a href="#home">Tax News</a>
  <a href="#home">Ask a Question</a>
  <a href="#news">Find an Accountant </a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Learn About Taxes 
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-contents">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</div>
```